# Multiple conditions in if statement (Liquid)

Tags: if-statement, liquid

Is it possible to put multiple conditions inside a single **if** statement in Shopify Liquid?

For example this is what I have:

```js
{% if product.type != "A" and product.type != "B" and product.type != "C" %}
//do something
{% endif %}
```

The reason I'm wondering is because **syntax highlighting stops after the first "and" operator**, as if everything after that has incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your syntax is 100% valid and will work in Shopify

```
{% if product.type != "A" and product.type != "B" and product.type != "C" %}
    //do something
{% endif %}
```

I guess the editor what you are using has a bug in syntax highlighter for liquid. That's why you confused

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Using Shopify's own code editor, guess it's buggy.