# Liquid : How do I combine two conditions?

Tags: conditional-statements, shopify, liquid

Liquid novice here looking for some help. I have two collections and one product in each collection that have similar names:

(collection) Snack Bars > (product)Chocolate Chip

(collection) Protein Bars > (product)Mint Chocolate Chip

I am trying to hide/show content specific to those items (within the same page) based on the collection and product handle. I've tried the following, but this shows both items even though == should be specific, it's not and displays as it considers chocolate-chip and chocholate-chip-mint to be a match, but it's not:

```
{% if product.handle == "chocolate-chip" %} // do something {% endif %}
```

I've tried this, but no go:

```
{% if collection == "protein-bars" && product.handle == "mint-chocolate-chip" %} // do something {% endif %}
```

I've also tried this but it doesn't work:

```
{% if product.handle == "mint-chocolate-chip" | within: collections.protein-bars %} // do something {% endif %}
```

Ultimately, I just want to verify that if I'm on a product page, my logic checks:

1. That the product handle in the URL matches (exactly) mint-chocolate-chip.
2. That the item is a part of the collection : protein-bars (not snack bars)

https://www.blakesseedbased.com/collections/snack-bars/products/chocolate-chip

https://www.blakesseedbased.com/collections/protein-bars/products/mint-chocolate-chip

You can see on the Mint Chocolate Chip page the logic believes "chocolate-chip" is a product match, and is displaying the information for chocolate-chip on the mint-chocolate-chip page (in the white section under the product display).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple conditions in if statement (Liquid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019799/multiple-conditions-in-if-statement-liquid)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I don't want to list out every product type this product "is not", there are a LOT of products this particular product isn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some things to keep in mind when writing your liquid statements:

- Liquid is verbose - it uses the literal words `and` and `or` for comparisons. Example: `{% if product.price > 1000 and product.price < 2000 %}`
- Conditionals cannot contain parentheses. Or at least, they *can* but they're ignored.  Result: Best practice is to only use `and` *or* `or` in any single statement.
- You cannot use filters inside of `if` (or `unless`) statements - you will want to use `assign` first to create a variable with all the filters applied first, then do your comparisons on that.
- In addition to `==`, `>`, `<` and `!=`, you can use `contains` inside your statements. If you're using `contains` on a string, you will match a substring; if you're using `contains` on an array, you will match an exact value in the array. (Note: you cannot use `contains` on an array of complex objects, like an array of variants)
- Collections are objects, so it can never equal a string. You should test for a collection based on some property, such as `collection.handle`
- The `map` filter is a handy way to reduce an array of complex objects into an array of simple fields

So something you could do:

```
{% assign product_collections = product.collections | map: 'handle' %}
{% if product_collections contains 'my-special-collection' and product.handle == 'my-special-handle' %}
  <h2>Hi Mom!</h2>
{% endif %}
```